# RestApi Libsodium SealedBox end-to-end request encryption scheme

Tags: encryption, tls, http, rest, end-to-end-encryption

I am making an API that uses the following steps for encryption. All of this is implemented using libsodium.

First of all the client has to make an initial request to the server for getting his public key and client token, with that key that corresponds to an unique sealedbox he encrypts and sends all the requests bodys. Once obtained he stores it locally

Then in order for the client to send a request to the server it has to encrypt the body ( create the sealedbox ) with the public key + ephemeral private key that's destroyed right after the encryption process.

Then the server takes the request and searches for the keypair generated for that client token in order to open the sealedbox.

When the server sends the response to the client is just a plain JSON

All connections to the server uses TLS 1.2+ + HSTS Header.

What do you think? Is it secure? Is there a better solution?

Do i need to implement Key exchange https://doc.libsodium.org/key_exchange in order to get the initial public key and client token to be completelysecure ?

Comment: 1) The traffic to the server is already encrypted with TLS. Why do you want to to encrypt it additionally? 2) To your question "Is it secure?" - even if you don't encrypt it is already secure. Secure against what threats do you mean?

Comment: @mentallurg 1) Yes of course , 2) It’s very sensitive user data, so my primary objective is to reduce to the minimum the risk of accessing that data even if the network is compromised and make sure that who is requesting that data is that user ( client token ), it’s just an idea , that is why I ask if there exists a better way of achieve the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** If you don't trust TLS, there is no easy way to establish secure data exchange.

You said that one of the threats is

> the network is compromised

If you don't trust network, then sending client token via such network makes no sense. Also all further steps that you described make no sense because they are based on a compromised client token.

Another threat is compromised authentication:

> make sure that who is requesting that data is that user

If you don't trust network, then you cannot trust user login. Means, you need to use some pre-shared secret which was shared via some *other*, trusted channel. For instance, you can send a list of *one-time* passwords to the client per SMS, or Email, or even per normal mail, or provide a *one-time-password* generator to each client.

Another approach may be using a separate public key on the server (for encryption of client requests) and public keys for each client. Actually, good practice is to use separate keys for signature and for encryption. Thus you need to provide 2 certificates to each client. Also you need to manage client certificates: Issue new certificates when the old ones expire, have a revocation list and organize revocation process.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time in respond , take into account that in the proposed scheme each client has an unique public key, so if in the initial request for getting the sealed box for that client the client sends his public key for receiving the response  ( client sealedbox ) and the server encrypts that pbkey and client token with the client sealedbox there is no way of someone reading the initial response but the original client right?. Authentication is managed with JWT after login

Comment: If you don't trust the network, then how will you answer these questions: 1) How will clients get server certificate? How will they know that certificate comes not from MIM? 2) How will server know that client certificate contained in the request comes from legitimate client, not from MIM?

Comment: I see you’re absolutely right, maybe I could use authentication ( encryption ) for the initial token with a known public key ? The server would have to sign each token and public key of the sealed box

Comment: How will you make the server public key *known* to the clients?

Comment: Hmm Hard coded in the code of the app or some way of public key exchange between the browser and the server ( the app is an angular app )

Comment: 1) Because of security reasons public keys normally have limited validity, e.g. 3 months. Then they are replaced with new ones. How will you do that? 2) In case you suspect the key was compromised you use new key and revoke the old one, i.e. you declare the old one as not trusted any more. For normal certificates there are certificate revocation lists. How will you do that?

Comment: I'm new on this but if i start to sign the initial responses with the client sealedboxes pkey and client token data ( that only happen one time ) with another privkey the signature has to be invalid right?. That would mean that the client is using an old version of the app, and has to update the app or refresh the browser.

I'm not using certificates per say just keypairs

Sealedbox: https://doc.libsodium.org/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes
PKey Signatures: https://doc.libsodium.org/public-key_cryptography/public-key_signatures

Comment: How will you know that client request comes from a legitimate client, not from MIM?

Comment: Because a MIM in order to make a request it has to stole the pkey of the sealedbox, maybe i could generate an one time use keypair for the initial connection ( when te client request the publickey and token ) , then the client sends in the body of that request his publickey and the server signs and encrypts the response with the publickey of the request body ? I don't know it's just a possible solution i think

Comment: At the beginning there is no sealed box. Your server obtains the very first request. How will you decide if this request comes from a legitimate client or from MIM?

Comment: Ah i misunderstood the question sorry, because it needs to have an already issued JWT token.

Comment: And how will get a JWT token, if you don't trust TLS?

Comment: I don’t trust the network , I do trust TLS that’s why I want to reduce the risk at minimum and use TLS 1.2>= with strong ciphers , if I can’t trust the initial connection I can’t trust the entire session between the server and the browser , I mean it’s more secure I think if I put in the hands of TLS the initial handshake and then the rest in hands of the sealedbox + TLS , the attacker just has one chance and one request . If for some reason the attacker get access to the TLS request of the session it still will be encrypted with the sealedbox

Comment: "the attacker just has one chance" - This does not make your whole scheme reliable. Either you trust TLS or not. If not, there should be no exception.

Comment: In general, you are not the first one who is considering secure end-to-end communication without relying on transport security (like TLS). For SOAP such standard exists since about 20 years: The first version of WSS (Web Service Security) was submitted in 2002. Even if you don't use SOAP, I'd suggest you look at concepts behind WSS.

Comment: Will do, knowledge is always appreciated, thank you

Comment: What do you think about this post ? https://soatok.blog/2020/11/14/going-bark-a-furrys-guide-to-end-to-end-encryption/ i could use that scheme for end to end encryption

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117665/discussion-between-mentallurg-and-leonel-franchelli).